# Imaginary variables in ImplicitRegion

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions, implicit

I am using the function ImplicitRegion[].

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == -1, {x, y}]]
```

[image]

which gives me a circle, though in the documentation variables are said to be real.

Adding additional assumption does not change anything:

```
RegionPlot[ Assuming[{x, y} \[Element] Reals, 
  ImplicitRegion[   x^2 + y^2 == -1, {{x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}}]]]
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) was working properly you would not get a plot. If you are trying to plot the equation:

```
funcs = y /. Solve[x^2 + y^2 == -1, y];

ReImPlot[funcs, {x, -Pi, Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[3], Automatic},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: But is there a way to tell ImplicitRegion that (x,y) are real and thus there are no solutions? I am using this function in NIntegrate so it's important not to get fake contours.

Comment: `ImplicitRegion` does not take an `Assumptions` option so you have to explicitly include the domain constraint. `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == -1 && Element[{x, y}, Reals], {x, y}], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]` will return an empty plot.

Comment: I tried changing -1 to 1 in your example and it gave an empty plot again.

Comment: Yes; however, you indicated that your actual problem is integration. Both `Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}]]` and `Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == -1, {x, y}]]` return the expected results. As do `Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1 && Element[{x, y}, Reals], {x, y}]]` and `Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == -1 && Element[{x, y}, Reals], {x, y}]]`

Comment: oh, I see, thanks! Perhaps the problem is related to RegionPlot.